# Shiny Directory selection

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a directory upload selection as the one described in this post [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-directory-input/29160/2) .

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage( # Application title
  mainPanel(
    shinyDirButton("dir", "Input directory", "Upload"),
    verbatimTextOutput("dir", placeholder = TRUE)  
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  shinyDirChoose(
    input,
    'dir',
    roots = c(home = '~'),
    filetypes = c('', 'txt', 'bigWig', "tsv", "csv", "bw")
  )
  
  global <- reactiveValues(datapath = getwd())
  
  dir <- reactive(input$dir)
  
  output$dir <- renderText({
    global$datapath
  })
  
  observeEvent(ignoreNULL = TRUE,
               eventExpr = {
                 input$dir
               },
               handlerExpr = {
                 if (!"path" %in% names(dir())) return()
                 home <- normalizePath("~")
                 global$datapath <-
                   file.path(home, paste(unlist(dir()$path[-1]), collapse = .Platform$file.sep))
               })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It works quite well, but when navigating on the file system on my machine, the only directory available is the "Downloads":

[image]

By going "Home" I can't select any directory on the list.

Answer (score 0):

The root directory is defined by `roots` argument.
`~` is usually your user's folder.
If you want to access to all available drives, try:

```
  shinyDirChoose(
    input,
    'dir',
    roots = getVolumes()(),
    filetypes = c('', 'txt', 'bigWig', "tsv", "csv", "bw")
  )
```

If you want to access current working directory:

```
roots = c(wd=getwd())
```

Comment: thanks for your help, what if I want the user to start on the current working directory?

Comment: sorry, I now get a single directory named "wd" that doesn't exist on my machine

Comment: do you have subdirectories in wd or filetypes in c('', 'txt', 'bigWig', "tsv", "csv", "bw")? if not dirchoose won't show anything

Comment: I have pdf and xlsx files, therefore, I've changed the next line to: filetypes = c('', 'pdf', 'xlsx')

Comment: Is this on your personal computer or on shiny server?

Comment: It's my own PC.

Comment: `dir(getwd())` gives you files with the expected extensions?

Comment: Yes, it gives me files with pdf, and xlsx files

Comment: I don't fully understand what happens. Perhaps try with `roots = c(wd='.')`